# plist python script hang

Tags: python, crash, plist, pickle

In OSX one of my python scripts that I launch via plist hangs. It hasn't allways hung. Sometimes it works for a while. It works fine if I launch it from terminal - python myscript.py. Its not an issue because of not using full paths. The script runs simultaneously to four other python scripts. It dump pickles information every ten minutes or so to six different files.

Can someone offer a direction for me to go in to find out why and fix the problem?